# Java Applet -manifest permission

Tags: java, applet, lang

I have a problem with permissions in the Manifest file. The applet did run with Java 7u45, but not with Java 7u51. When I rebuild my application with Java 7u51 I get this error:

> Missing Application-Name manifest attribute for: http://desenvolvimento.conectbox.com.br/acesso_cliente/central_nfe/saida/assinador/NFE_UTILAssinado.jar Missing Permissions manifest attribute in main jar: http://desenvolvimento.conectbox.com.br/acesso_cliente/central_nfe/saida/assinador/NFE_UTILAssinado.jar 0 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source) at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source) at nfe_util.AppletNFE_UTIL.init(AppletNFE_UTIL.java:18) at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source) at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

So how can I solve this and make my applet run?

Comment: what is the level of java security on the system ?

Comment: So.. what is your question?

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

Andrew. my question is: how can i solve this and make my applet run?

Niks, the level of java security system is "medium" (the lower one).